# New dataframe row by row from a different format dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm wandering if something like this could be achieved with python.

I currently have the following dataframe (df1):

```
  A       B       C      D      E      F   
1.1.1   amba     131     1     50      4      
2.2.2   erto     50      7     131     8
3.3.3   gema     131     2     50      5
```

And I would like to get this output in a new dataframe (df2):

```
 ID     User    131      50
1.1.1   amba     1       4
2.2.2   erto     8       7
3.3.3   gema     2       5
```

Take in mind that df1 has an undetermined number of rows and df2 should have the same number of rows than df1. First and second column do not change and keep the same. Columns C and E in df1 store attribute IDs while columns D and F store attribute's values. For example, in df1 131=1 and 50=4 in the first row. Plus attribute IDs are not always in the same column and the attribute ID could be placed in Column C or column E.

I am thinking on creating df2 using a loop and analyzing rows with lambda but i am currently having issues to make work anything for the moment. Any idea?

---

I have understood evey part of the code and I am now adding columns but I am wondering if this could be done with a loop or something similar. This is how code looks after adding 4 extra colums:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""  A       B       C      D      E      F      G      H      I       J     
1.1.1   amba     131     1     50      4      40       3       150       5   
2.2.2   erto     50      7     40      8      150      8       131       2
3.3.3   gema     131     2    150      5      40       1        50       3"""), sep="\s+")



df2 = (pd.concat([df1.drop(columns=["C","D","E","F","G","H"]).rename(columns={"I":"key","J":"val"}),
           df1.drop(columns=["C","D","E","F","I","J"]).rename(columns={"G":"key","H":"val"}),
           df1.drop(columns=["C","D","G","H","I","J"]).rename(columns={"E":"key","F":"val"}),
           df1.drop(columns=["E","F","G","H","I","J"]).rename(columns={"C":"key","D":"val"}),
          ])
 .rename(columns={"A":"ID","B":"User"})
 .set_index(["ID","User","key"])
 .unstack(2)
 .reset_index()
)

# flatten the columns..
df2.columns = [c[1] if c[0]=="val" else c[0] for c in df2.columns.to_flat_index()]
df2


print(df2)
```

And this is the output:

```
      ID  User  40  50  131  150
0  1.1.1  amba   3   4    1    5
1  2.2.2  erto   8   7    2    8
2  3.3.3  gema   1   3    2    5
```

So yes, everything is working fine but I would like to find a way to make this with a loop instead of having tons of lines (I have about 70 columns per row). Thank you very much for the help. Thanks.

---

I have just one extra question and I will have everything working fine. In my actual table I have some rows with 60 columns nd other ones with just 30 or so. This means that I have tons of NaN in these rows with less colums, so I am getting an error when try to unstack. I have read about pivot_tables, drop_duplicates, etc, but not sure how to make work some of these options with this code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically you have a mix of keys being part of row and part of columns.  Construct a df by `concat()` that has the whole key as part of the row.  Then it's a simple case of using `unstack()` to get what you want

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""  A       B       C      D      E      F   
1.1.1   amba     131     1     50      4      
2.2.2   erto     50      7     131     8
3.3.3   gema     131     2     50      5"""), sep="\s+")


df2 = (pd.concat([df1.drop(columns=["C","D"]).rename(columns={"E":"key","F":"val"}),
           df1.drop(columns=["E","F"]).rename(columns={"C":"key","D":"val"}),
          ])
 .rename(columns={"A":"ID","B":"User"})
 .set_index(["ID","User","key"])
 .unstack(2)
 .reset_index()
)

# flatten the columns..
df2.columns = [c[1] if c[0]=="val" else c[0] for c in df2.columns.to_flat_index()]
df2
```

**output**

```
    ID  User  50  131
 1.1.1  amba   4    1
 2.2.2  erto   7    8
 3.3.3  gema   5    2
```

......

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. I actually have +60 columns and not just 6 like in the example. Plus some rows have more "attribute" and "attribute.value" columns that other, but you have given me a great starting point :-).

Comment: I guessed that ...  there is full symmetry in way key/value DF is built so can be extended to many more columns

Comment: Bit short of time...  you can achieve what you want as a list comprehension of list that is passed to `concat()`.  Probably better to `df1.loc[:,[fixedcols, keycol, valcol].rename()` as well rather than drop all the unwanted columns